# Oil pressure blowing through filter gasket, but gauge shows pressure is ok

Tags: oil, leak, pressure

As I'm getting ready for breaking the engine I just rebuilt (Skoda Estelle/120 '70s, RWD, rear mounted engine) I wanted to start checking things before firing it, even before cranking it. I made a rod that engages the oil pump shaft and with a drill I started pumping oil while, obviously, the engine is not running. I also attached an oil pressure gauge which comes with an idiot lamp. As the pump started to raise pressure, I got it blowing out through the oil filter gasket. Gauge shows good reading. Idiot lamp got turned off. So I tightened the filter further but still get pressure being blown.

Question, what could make this? The gasket is kinda old and I couldn't replace it since it has some special profile...and it was holding well before rebuild. Is oil pressure so violent at filter area to just escape if the gasket is not "new"?

Answer (score 1):

The oil pressure that the gasket has to deal with is the same in all parts of the circuit unless here is an inline pressure regulator (not the same a a pressure relief valve).

If it is leaking then you need to replace it either purchase one or make one...

Comment: But the leak is not only a leak :) it is actually "blowing" pressure...like a opening a disturbed soda can!

Comment: If it is gushing out "then you need to replace it either purchase one or make one"

Comment: having seen your other comment below, is it a rubber ring ? if so, then a friendly parts store may help you find an equivalent... a vernier caliper will be very useful...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this in a long time but it is possible you have two gaskets. On rare occasions the gasket sticks to the oil filter mount when the filter is removed. When you install the new filter the double gasket leaks like a sieve.

Comment: Nope, I have only one gasket. This is the kind of filter where the filter element is inside a canister...you change the element only.